# Why do some functions in Perl have to be called with parens and others don't?

Tags: perl

An example to illustrate is the Synopsis of my own [`Test::Version`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Version/lib/Test/Version.pm).

```
use Test::More;
use Test::Version 0.04;

# test blib or lib by default
version_all_ok();

done_testing;
```

I don't have to include parenthesis on `done_testing();` I can simply call it. However when I've tried to call `version_all_ok;` *( note: First attempt at Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Test::Version failed this way)* I get an error. Why is this?

**Update** Perhaps my example is not quite as good as I've thought. The actual error I've gotten is

```
Bareword "version_all_ok" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at t/release-test-version.t line 19.
```

and here's the full code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

BEGIN {
  unless ($ENV{RELEASE_TESTING}) {
    require Test::More;
    Test::More::plan(skip_all => 'these tests are for release candidate testing');
  }
}

use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

eval "use Test::Version";
plan skip_all => "Test::Version required for testing versions"
    if $@;

version_all_ok; # of course line 19, and version_all_ok() works here.
done_testing;
```

The following should be relevant snippets pulled from `Test::Version 1.0.0` for exportation.

```
use parent 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw( version_all_ok ); ## no critic (Modules::ProhibitAutomaticExportation)
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( version_ok );
```

Comment: lot's of great answers here... so I'm just gonna pick one, though more than one of them is correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fundamentally, because Perl needs to know that a bareword means a function call in order to parse it as a function call.  There are two ways Perl might learn this interesting fact:

1. You might have decorated the bareword like a function call, prepending `&` or `->` or appending `(...)` or both.  Perl will trust that you know what you're talking about and parse the bareword as a function call even if it doesn't yet know what function it will have to call.
2. You might have declared a function with that name before Perl tries to parse the call.  Ordinarily, `use`-ing a module is enough to ensure the symbols get created at the right time; you're doing something wrong in `Test::Version` such that the symbol is not getting exported until after it is needed to compile the test script.

In your code, you wrap the `use` inside an `eval`, which effectively delays it until execution time.  Consequently, the symbol `version_all_ok` is not available when Perl tries to compile the call and it blows up.  Forcing the `eval` to compile time should suffice to make the symbol available:

```
BEGIN {
    eval "use Test::Version";
    plan skip_all => "Test::Version required for testing versions"
        if $@;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This example shows (clearly I think) that all you need is to predeclare the function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub hi {
  print "hi\n";
}

hi; #could be `hi();`
bye();  #could not be `bye;`

sub bye {
  print "bye\n";
}
```

If your sensibilities require that you define your subroutines at the bottom, but you want them to be callable without parens (as though predeclared), you may use the [`subs`](http://p3rl.org/subs) pragma:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use subs qw/hi bye/;

hi;
bye;

sub hi {
  print "hi\n";
}

sub bye {
  print "bye\n";
}
```

UPDATE:
It would appear that the `subs` pragma can even alleviate problems from string evals. You might try a `use subs 'version_all_ok';` near the top of your script. My proof of concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use subs qw/hi bye/;

eval <<'DECLARE';
sub bye {
  print "bye\n";
}
DECLARE

hi;
bye;

sub hi {
  print "hi\n";
}
```

Comment: Interesting, though I wonder why then that Perl thinks my function isn't predeclared... (where thinks means isn't but the reason isn't obvious to me)

Comment: I have to think its the loading in an `eval` rather than a straight compile-time `use`. Its not often that the compile-time vs run-time problem hits you. Its the compiler that throws the error. I guess what I should have said in my answer is 'predeclared at compile-time.'

Answer (score 2):

I can't duplicate this using Test::Version 1.0.0 or 0.04.  Is it possible you weren't exporting what you thought you were?

Can you double check and provide both the full script that failed, the error message, and full script that succeeded, and the perl version you are using?

Update: ok, you are loading Test::Version at runtime; that means that when `version_all_ok` is encountered at compile time, there is no such subroutine.  There isn't any way around this without modifying the test script in some way, such as:

```
my $has_test_version;
BEGIN { $has_test_version = eval "use Test::Version; 1" }
plan skip_all => "Test::Version required for testing versions" if ! $has_test_version;
```

Comment: @ysth, It would appear that the `subs` pragma can help with string eval'ed function declarations, perhaps this will also help string eval'ed module loading.

Comment: @Joel: yes, but better to just make sure the module is loaded at compile time

Answer (score 0):

It just needs to be declared before your use, still using the parentheses or ampersand should be used for distinction and clarity.

Comment: the ampersand has special meanings and shouldn't be used just for clarity because unintended consequences may occur. parens are encouraged for clarity.

Comment: Yes and no, it should be used for clarity and distinction, when appropriate.  Like what you probably meant, ampersands provide functions with other functionality, such as the inherit pass of `@_`.  See [the perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What's-the-difference-between-calling-a-function-as-%26foo-and-foo()%3f) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

It's allowed if the function has been declared before, and it would be treated as a list operator (WARNING: it could change operator precedence!)

Answer (score -2):

From [Programming Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000271/), chapter 29 *Functions*:

> Predefined Perl functions may be used either with or without parentheses around their arguments; the syntax summaries in this chapter omit the parentheses. If you do use parentheses, the simple but occasionally surprising rule is this: if it looks like a function, then it is a function, so precedence doesn't matter. Otherwise, it's a list operator or unary operator, and precedence does matter. Be careful, because even if you put whitespace between the keyword and its left parenthesis, that doesn't keep it from being a function

Found on p.677 (missing online at [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=xx5JBSqcQzIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=programming+perl&hl=en&ei=nnspTp7HIYbBtgfe7qDXAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) due to copyright) -- every Perl programmer should have the camel book.

Comment: The question is not related to the ability to invoke builtins without parens; it's explicitly about how calls to subs are parsed.

Comment: @darch a predefined function doesn't have to be a builtin.  Predefinition doesn't imply native and doesn't distinguish author.  Predefined means it has been declared before it has been called, please learn the semantics.

Comment: "Declared" means "has been declared".  When _Programming Perl_ uses the word "predefined", it's exactly talking about things built into Perl.  In fact, the sentence you quoted is explicit about it.  Please do a text search.

Comment: @Darch... no there is a difference between declared and predefined and predefined does not mean "builtin", though builtin functions are predefined, so I understand your confusion, but you're wrong.  If you do not prototype a function, you both declare it and define it.  If you only prototype it, you declare it.

Comment: please don't link to pirated material

Comment: @Brian, you're exactly right (+1)... I hope someone can erase it from the rollback history.  I didn't check the path from Google.  BTW, do you know if a new version of the book is planned to be released?  This one is getting pretty old :)

Comment: The next Programming Perl comes out in October.

Comment: Nice, what day are you presenting next week?

Comment: I don't see why this is still being downrated.  I've modified the answer and agreed to my mistake.  The answer is still correct; if you don't agree, you can take it up with Larry Wall.